# Display statistics on how my triage votes compare to actual results

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage

I am really curious to find out how my votes in triage align with the actual final triage results.  This could take several forms, from a simple high-level summary at the "Needs Improvement"/OK/Unsalvageable level, to detailed close reasons or even a list of your votes you can slice/dice along various dimensions such as consensus, close reason, etc.

Is this something of interest to the general community?

Comment: I can plug my [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100) if you like? oh, I just did.....

Comment: @rene: If you hadn't I woulda.